# ActiveMQ web console - how to point to a hostname or IP address instead of localhost?

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

Is there a way to point the ActiveMQ on a public IP address such as `https://{ip address}:8161/admin/`?

Answer (score 2):

If by `{ip address}` you're willing to accept `127.0.0.1` it's a no-brainer :-)

Since I'm running an Apache on my ActiveMQ box anyway, I ended up adding a `VirtualHost` and forward to ActiveMQ's Jetty by way of `mod_proxy`:

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.1.123:80>
    # Change IP above as fits your LAN/WAN.
    ServerName activemq.your.domain

    ProxyRequests On
    ProxyVia On

    ProxyPass        / http://localhost:8161/
</VirtualHost>
```

Don't forget proper security!

**Edit**: I got curious and trawled through the ActiveMQ and Jetty config, and it seems obvious that adding

```
<property name="host" value="your.host.name.or.IP" />
```

to

```
<bean id="Connector" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
    <property name="port" value="8161" />
    <property name="host" value="your.host.name.or.IP" />  <!-- added -->
</bean>
```

in `conf/jetty.xml` does the trick.

Cheers,

Comment: i think it works for apache only not for apache activemq... any more suggestions that work on mq?

Comment: @Shudmeyer This is not an example of how to configure jetty (which normally serves the ActiveMQ web console) but how to set up a reverse proxy with apache httpd which listens on a server which is potentially reachable via a public IP and is configured to forward the requests to your web console. The concrete example uses a private IP for the reverse proxy and assumes that the reverse proxy runs on the same machine as the web console.

Comment: I have added info on how to achieve this within the scope of the ActiveMQ config.

Comment: The web console doesn't seem to work nicely when behind a reverse proxy, see this related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57220506/configure-base-url-for-activemq-web-console-running-behind-a-reverse-proxy